# How to get my messages to show on Django for a registration form?

Tags: python, django, forms, message

I am creating a registration form using the Django framework and I want to display some error messages to the user if they enter the wrong confirm password, or an email already taken etc. I have written the code and it seems to be working, but I can't seem to get the messages to show on screen upon redirecting to back to registration page if there is an error in the form. I have imported messages on the views.py page (from django.contrib import messages) and I think my setting.py is all configured correct: [setting.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqvJN.png)

Here is my views.py code:

```
def register(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    register_form = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, "main/register.html", {
        'form': register_form
    })
else:
    register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if register_form.is_valid():
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        last_name = request.POST['last_name']
        username = request.POST['username']
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        confirm_password = request.POST['confirm_password']


        if password == confirm_password:
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                    messages.info(request, 'Email or user name Already taking')
                    return redirect('register')
            elif User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
                    messages.info(request, 'username is taken')
                    return redirect('register')
            else:
                User.objects.get_or_create(username=username, 
                first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, 
                password=password)
                
                return redirect('main/login.html')
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Password Not Match')
            return redirect('register')   
        #return redirect ('/')     
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/login.html')
```

and this is my register.html form:

```
          <form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Enter details</legend>
                    <ul>
                        {{ form.as_table }}
                    
                        <button type="submit" class="mybutton _f-purple" value="submit">Register</button>
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: You can use django crispy forms for easy form rendering. Here's the link: https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you need.

```html
          {% if messages %}
            <div class="mgs-area">
                <div class="mgs-item">
                {% for message in messages %}
                <span {% if message.tags %} class="nav_item message-{{ message.tags }} " {% endif %}> {{ message }} </span>
                {% endfor %}
                </div>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
```

You can style success or error messages differently.

> class="nav_item message-{{ message.tags }}